# angularjs filter based on particular key (exact match)

Tags: angularjs, filter

I want to filter an angularjs array say,

```
$scope.myObj = [
       {id:1,name:'foo'},
       {id:2,name:'bar'},
       {id:10,name:'quad'},
       {id:13,name:'cad'}
    ]
```

based particularly on `id = 1`. If i use

```
console.log($filter('filter')($scope.myObj, 1));
```

it will return all the object that contain `1`. How can i restrict to filter only required object?

**EDIT:** It can solved by using `true for exact match based on answer below.

```
console.log($filter('filter')($scope.myObj, {id: 1}, true));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute below code to filter data by ID column:

```
var filterObjList=$filter('filter')($scope.myObj, {id:1}, true);
if(filterObjList && filterObjList.length>0)
return filterObjList[0];
```

If you want to filter the list by name then replace "Id" with "name" and pass the value in single inverted commas.

Comment: it fails when `{id:0}`. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/uz1d371e/1/

Comment: It can be solved by using `true` for exact match. https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/uz1d371e/3/. Update ur answer and i'll accept it :)